# tcl procedure not working

Tags: regex, tcl

I am writing a procedure to o/p the errors/severity/Occurrence from a file to table format ,but its not working.

Snippet of file:

```
error_name: xxxxxxxxxx
 Severity: Warning Occurrence: 2 
error_name2:xxxxxxxxxxx. 
Severity: Warning Occurrence: 16 
error_name3:xxxxxxxxxxxxx 
Severity: Warning Occurrence: 15
```

Code:

```
proc get_clp_summary { Infile } {
   set run_summary_file  [ glob $Infile/summary.rpt ]

   set fp [ open $run_summary_file   "r" ]

   while { [ gets $fp line ]!= -1 } {
      foreach {match label value} [regexp -inline -all {(\w+):\s*(\S*)} $line] {
         switch -exact -- $label {
            Severity   {set sev $value}
            Occurrence {set count $value}
            default    {set err $label}
         }
         lappend pack_stats [ list $err $sev $count] 
         puts $pack_stats              
      }

      return $pack_stats
   }


   ##################################################################

   set run_time_stats [ get_clp_summary [ lindex $argv 0 ]  ]

   puts ""
   puts ""
   puts ""

   table_styler
   puts " \<table id=\"customers\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\" \> "
   puts "\<th\>  Rule \<\/th\>"
   puts "\<th\>  Severity   \<\/th\>"
   puts "\<th\>  Occurrence  \<\/th\>"
   puts "\<\/tr\>"
   foreach k $run_time_stats {

      set st [ lindex $k 0 ]
      set st_type [ lindex $k 1 ]
      set st_count [lindex $k 2]
      set BGCOLOR #FFFFFF 
      puts " \<tr\> \<td\> $st \<\/\> \<td bgcolor=\"$BGCOLOR\" \> $st \<\/td\> "
      puts "\<td\> \<td bgcolor=\"$BGCOLOR\" \> $st_type \<\/td\>  \"                        
      puts "\<td\>  $st_count  \<\/td\> "
      puts "\<\/tr\>"
   }

   puts " \<\/table\> "
}

puts " \<\/body\> "
puts " \<\/html\> "
```

Comment: Please define "not working". What is it giving you? An error? No output?

Comment: It does not o/p anything

Answer (score 1):

Here are some observation.

- You code does output the *body* and *html* tags
- You wrote the procedure `get_clp_summary`, but did not call it. That is why it does not output anything. You need to call it, like this:

  ```
  get_clp_summary filename
  ```
- Please do not use abbreviation/short hand. It took me a while to figure out **o/p** means output. Yes, I am that dumb.
- As a matter of style, please work on indentation for your code. It should greatly help with readability.

Comment: +1 for the "Please do not use abbreviation". There are ppl that are cap. to write things with a lot abvr so n/o can understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're not clean with your indentation. A trivial thing, but it's causing you *major* problems.

Here's why. When I reindented your submission, I found that the procedure `get_clp_summary` was actually ending many lines later than I initially thought! That means that it is never called (there's a recursive call from some unreachable code inside the procedure, which I don't think you want). If you get the indentation right, perhaps using the support of a programmers' editor, then you'll pick up on problems like misplaced braces much more rapidly.

To fix the code, take the brace after:

```
puts " \<\/table\> "
```

and put it *before*

```
return $pack_stats
```

Oh, and there are *many* other problems in that code. There's at least one backslash that will cause total chaos in that HTML printing part (and Tcl doesn't need a `\` before a `<` or `>` anyway). What's more, you don't close the channel that you're reading from, and you're assuming that `glob` returns a single file (it returns a list, even if it is a list with one element sometimes). You might want to look at using `subst`, like this:

```
puts [subst {
<table id="customers" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
   <tr>
      <th> Rule </th>
      <th> Severity </th>
      <th> Occurrence </th>
   </tr>
}]
foreach k $run_time_stats {
   # Consider using:  lassign $k st st_type st_count
   set st [lindex $k 0]
   set st_type [lindex $k 1]
   set st_count [lindex $k 2]
   set BGCOLOR "#FFFFFF"
   puts [subst {
      <tr>
         <td bgcolor="$BGCOLOR"> $st </td>
         <td bgcolor="$BGCOLOR"> $st_type </td>
         <td> $st_count </td>
      </tr>
   }]
}
puts "</table>"
```

Comment: Thanks ,I tried it but it gives error can't read "sev": no such variable
    while executing
"list $err $sev $count"
    (procedure "get_clp_summary" line 13)
    invoked from within
"get_clp_summary [ lindex $argv 0 ]  "
    invoked from within
"set run_time_stats [ get_clp_summary [ lindex $argv 0 ]  ]"

Comment: Hi Can Someone please suggest on this ? It does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `foreach` loop which parses file line by line. Once first line is read, it has no severity or count information, so it fails because variables `$sev` and `$count` are still unset.

A rather rough but working example and not deviating too far from your code would be like this.

```
while { [ gets $fp line ]!= -1 } {
    foreach {match label value} [regexp -inline -all {(\w+):\s*(\S*)} $line] {
        switch -exact -- $label {
            Severity   {set sev $value}
            Occurrence {set count $value}
            default    {set err $value}
        }
        if { [info exists err] && [info exists sev] && [info exists count] } {
            lappend pack_stats [ list $err $sev $count]
            unset err sev count
        }
  }
```

It checks until all three variables are collected and set, then appends return list, and then unsets them so they can be collected again. Also corrected the `default    {set err $label}` piece as thought it's a value, not label is what you want. Please revert if my assumption was wrong.